# The uniqueness of Poincaré metric

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, modular-forms, hyperbolic-geometry

The Poincaré metric $ds=\frac{\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}}{y}$ has the proprety that the action of the group $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})=SL(2,\mathbb{R})/\{\pm I_{2}\}$ on $\mathbb{H}$ preserves the hyperbolic distance.

My question is if there are other metrics on $\mathbb{H}$ such that the action of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ preserves the distance related to these metrics? I have taken a look at some books on Riemannian manifolds and don't find a result of unicity like this.

Comment: this is proven here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1324474/unique-metric-for-the-hyperbolic-half-plane-model

Comment: There are other invariant metrics, for example the "chordal metric". Poincare metric is the unique (up to constant factor) invariant Riemannian metric. (You omitted the word "Riemannian" in your question).

Comment: Can this be generalized: is Bergman metric the unique (modulo constant multiple) Hermitean metric on a homogeneous complex manifold, which is invariant with respect to complex automorphisms?